# phpBB Custom fields for a certain field identification

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to display a value from a custom profile field if the field has a value.

Traditionally phpBB has the following inside `viewtopic_body.html`

```
<!-- BEGIN custom_fields -->
<dd><strong>{postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_NAME}:</strong> {postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_VALUE}</dd>
<!-- END custom_fields -->
```

My field identification name is `myprojectsthread` and has been **added after** the above code. I have placed a value into my own profile and used the following code to display the custom field

```
<!-- IF postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_MYPROJECTTHREAD_NAME -->
<dd><a href="/board/viewtopic.php?{postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_MYPROJECTTHREAD_NAME}">My Project Thread</a></dd>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Successfully the link shows but the value after `viewtopic.php?` doesn't show and the link is invalid.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- IF postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_NAME eq "My Project Thread Name" -->
<dd><a href="/board/viewtopic.php?{postrow.custom_fields.PROFILE_FIELD_VALUE}">My Project Thread</a></dd>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

[phpbb](/questions/tagged/phpbb)[phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3)

Comment: I never realised till late yesterday it needed to be the field name not the field identifier. Oops